# User control posts back but does not render

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, user-controls, ektron

I have one user control called calculator that is registered on  a usercontrol (ektron widget). Two instances of these  calculator controls are added to the widget in  different panels. These panels make use of partial postbacks.

```
<asp:Panel runat="server"  ID="pnlStep1">
<uc1:send_Calculator ID="stage1_Calculator"  runat="server" />
</panel>
<asp:Panel runat="server"  ID="pnlStep2">
<uc1:send_Calculator ID="stage2_Calculator" runat="server" />
```

The calculator control has a dropdownlist and a textbox.On the selectedindexchanged event all it does is change the value of a textbox i.e.

```
 protected void ddlCountries_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)

 {  tbExample.Text ="bla bla";  }
```

This functionality works for the first instance of the calculator  control and the text changes but for the   second instance of the control the event triggers so the postback has worked but the textbox does not change value. Its like it got lost somewhere on the way back to the client.

Any ideas why the one calc control would work and the other one wouldn't?

Comment: "Its like it got lost somewhere on the way back to the client" - If that's the case, can you write it to the console? The key is to find out where it's failing. What's being returned? Tools like the debugger and Firebug may help you figure it out.

Comment: This is old but unanswered. Did you resolve it? If not, one useful approach is to use a browser dev tools like Chrome Dev Tools or FireFox built-in or FireBug. Enable the Net Panel and watch what happens for the requests there, and in console, when you click the second list. If you got it resolved, can you post up what you found?